# Electronics course - From basics to designing circuits

Tags: basic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [From zero to “almost pro”: Newbie trying to learn. Good, quick resources?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/from-zero-to-almost-pro-newbie-trying-to-learn-good-quick-resources)
> [What good resources are there for a high school student to start learning electronics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/what-good-resources-are-there-for-a-high-school-student-to-start-learning-electr)

I am trying to learn electronics. I have a number of books and have been through the basics

- Ohms Law
- Resistors
- Capacitors
- Diodes
- Etc...

The books I have go through these fundamentals quite well but then they show some circuits for me to build. I would like to learn how to design a circuit and not just copy an existing one.
For example, I know what capacitors are and how they work but I have no idea how to design them into a DC circuit.

Is there a good Electronics course online or a good book which will teach me.

Comment: I am guessing one or more of these questions will give you what you need to know: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MIT is offering for free their [Circuits & Electronics](https://6002x.mitx.mit.edu/) online this spring. If you do the homework and pass the test you will even get a certificate from MIT. Of course you can simply audit it if you prefer.

> 6.002x (Circuits and Electronics) is designed to serve as a first course in an undergraduate electrical engineering (EE), or electrical
>   engineering and computer science (EECS) curriculum. At MIT, 6.002 is
>   in the core of department subjects required for all undergraduates in
>   EECS.
>
> The course introduces engineering in the context of the lumped circuit
>   abstraction. Topics covered include: resistive elements and networks;
>   independent and dependent sources; switches and MOS transistors;
>   digital abstraction; amplifiers; energy storage elements; dynamics of
>   first- and second-order networks; design in the time and frequency
>   domains; and analog and digital circuits and applications. Design and
>   lab exercises are also significant components of the course. You
>   should expect to spend approximately 10 hours per week on the course.

Comment: For anyone else interested this course is very good and has very good material and resources. You can view most of the content as a guest if you have missed registration of the course. Highly recomend

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a hybrid between an online course and a book, is All About Circuits: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com  I use it a lot as a reference, covers pretty much everything.  Main topics are DC, AC, Semiconductors, Digital circuits, reference materials (resistor codes, math, etc.), and a bunch of experiments you can do.