# I Need Help Making a Weird Custom Flashlight

Tags: batteries, switches, wireless, wiring, light

As said in the title, I am trying to make a homemade flashlight. I have no experience when it comes to electrical engineering and I have a very basic understanding of this stuff. What I am trying to make is a simple flashlight that you can turn off and on with a switch, but with another added feature of a wireless switch. My goal is to be able to turn on and off the flashlight wirelessly as well as with an attached switch.

The flashlight doesn't have to be super bright or anything powerful. Any light that will let me see in the dark fine is good. I just want it to be powered by batteries and have two switches. I know most batteries like AA have 1.5 volts, which I can use to power an LED or something, which is about as far as my knowledge goes. The trouble comes with the switches.

This wireless switch from Amazon looks good, it has all the features I want:
[https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Wireless-Control-1-Channel-Transmitters/dp/B071WM1YGS/ref=asc_df_B071WM1YGS/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=216539147262&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17788182304608934384&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9021532&hvtargid=pla-351410254745&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WM1YGS)

Keep in mind I don't even know if this wireless switch will even work for what I'm doing.

I know too much voltage is not good for smaller bulbs and such, so I am here to ask for advice on what specific components I need to put this thing together. The wireless switch says it's 12 volts, so I assume I need 8 batteries to power it. After that I am clueless to the current and  resistors and ohms and all of that stuff you smart guys know about. I would greatly appreciate a list of the things I need when it comes to the light bulb and switches along with any tips you could give me. Thank you for reading my request!

Comment: if it's to be battery powered, you need a very low power receiver. The one you linked is for mains operation, so will be power-hungry. Buy an existing battery-powered receiver, perhaps a cordless doorbell, and hack that into a torch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this site is set up for answer very specific, targeted questions. It is not set up to deliver a course in electronics.

It is likely you can build your project by assembling various pre-made components, but to understand how to connect the components together you will still need a basic understanding of electronics theory.

For learning electronics there are at least two discussions on this site which you may find helpful:

- [What good resources are there for a high school student to start learning electronics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/what-good-resources-are-there-for-a-high-school-student-to-start-learning-electr)
- [From zero to “almost pro”: Newbie trying to learn. Good, quick resources?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/from-zero-to-almost-pro-newbie-trying-to-learn-good-quick-resources)

There may be more -- just use the search facility on this site for "learning electronics".

Note that there are a lot of commercial products which seem to do what you describe. Searching for "battery operated wireless light" or "battery operated remote light" brings up a lot of potential products.

Comment: Thank you very much