# Calculating the voltage produced by Radio frequency

Tags: voltage, rf

How do you calculate the voltage produced by a radio frequencies? Say, you have 100MHz radio frequency, whats the relation to calculate voltage produced by it?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You need E-field strength (at specific frequency) to calculate voltage made by the E-field of that particular frequency.

Comment: Ron, seeing your questions, that are absolutely welcome, I would suggest you to start from the basic theory about electricity, and getting into step by step. This specific questions will hardly bring you far.

Comment: @clabacchio: Yes, I feel somewhat lost but where should I start? Is there a particular easy to read book? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't read it entirely, but you can find some books here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book or also wiki-books must have something

Comment: Clearly this question can't be answered as the units don't even check.

Answer (score 2):

Radio frequency in an of itself does not have a direct correlation to voltage. A 100 MHz radio could have a voltage of 100v or 10v or 5v or whatever you want it to be. Once you put this voltage on to an antenna, it will radiate that frequency into the air. You can calculate the losses that this signal will have in the air by using the [Free-space path loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss).

Typically people are concerned more about the power that is transmitted and received instead of the voltage. The reason for this is that the amount of power that is received determines if the receiver will be able to interpret the signal correctly.