# Online guide to electronics

Tags: tutorial, documentation

I had the luck to have someone who could explain everything to me, but most starting hobbyists don't have someone like that. Is there a guide available which covers all the basics, like formulas, parallel / series, etc.?

Comment: http://sound.westhost.com/articles.htm

Comment: Uhm, how about this stack exchange? :) If the question is good, it's still useful even if basic. As the "about" page say: "This is a free, community driven Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. "

Comment: A random smattering of questions and answers with all difficulty levels mixed in is hardly a useful narrative. Its nice if you have something specific to ask, but not so useful if you want learn the basics with no large gaps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Garrett said, there are a lot of beginner electronics websites out there. My favorites are:

- http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws
- http://www.allaboutcircuits.com
- http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/study.htm
- http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/index.php
- http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html -> Electricity
  and Magnetism
- http://www.pyroelectro.com/edu/basics/
- http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/electronics/
- http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/electronics/
- http://www.renesas.com/edge_ol/engineer/index.jsp
- [Circuits and Electronics (6.002x)](https://6002x.mitx.mit.edu/) - free online electronics course from MIT

Answer (score 5):

There are a ton of websites and tutorials, I got started from books, and we have a good list [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/616/9730) as for a site, [Electronics Theory](http://electronicstheory.com/COURSES/ELECTRONICS/e101-1.htm) has a good free course that starts very basic and very detailed.

Another site that has a lot of video and stuff is [101 Science](http://101science.com/Radio.htm).

For a bit more advanced user (not much more, but it isn't an intro into electronics,) [Electronics Lab](http://www.electronics-lab.com/) has a lot of projects and stuff, they even sell kits, and they buy designs and tutorials if you feel like writing one, I've done it years ago. And [EEV Blog](http://eevblog.com) is a great source for the more advanced person, great very popular videos! Highly recommended, and they have a forum too!