# What course of study is important for someone wanting to make analog audio equipment?

Tags: audio, theory

I do not have a background in electrical engineering. I do have experience building audio equipment from kits and I can build circuits from schematics diagrams.

What I would like to do is to be able to build more creatively. I don't think I will be able to do this without a more rigorous, abstract understanding of how audio signals are generated and manipulated in hardware though.

I would like to study some essential theory but I don't want to get an entire electrical engineering degree. What would be the most direct way to gain this knowledge? (a certain course, book recommendations, etc)

Comment: What you are interested in is "analog electronics". But this is a better question for chat than for the main site, because "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: This question is very broad and likely to get closed soon for the reason @ThePhoton points out. However, you might want to have a look at these questions: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/53231/17592 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/616/17592

Comment: Unfortunately this user does not have enough rep to participate in chat. I agree the question should be closed, but with four upvotes (it is a good question) he'd have enough to chat. Downvotes are just making that harder.

Comment: One simple answer almost anywhere will help with that also.