# Arduino starter

Tags: arduino

I have finished my first year in engineering and would like to do some projects related to arduino. What should we do as a starter?

Comment: What area interests you?

Comment: What do you mean by "feasible"?

Comment: Embedded systems.

Comment: Taking into consideration that I have completed only my first year in engineering , what would be the best course I could do . That's what I meant by feasible

Comment: You're good. Just try to get a balance between circuit design/theory and software in your coursework. In the US, some schools  offer a "computer engineering" major that is a good fit for people interested in embedded systems.

Comment: Books: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/616/2028

Comment: @DannyPaul Pretty much 90% of arduino projects are doable at your level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little like: "What field can I specialize in if I am a medical student?"

The answer is: "Whatever you like."

Seriously, doctors aren't forced to become knee surgeons or oncologists. They do so because of their interests, aptitude, and often colleagues or institutions that they know or are familiar with.

Electrical engineers are the same way. If you're interested in cross-country power delivery and generation, focus on transmission lines and high voltage. If you want to develop atom-sized transistors or nanometer-scale integrated circuits, you can specialize in that, instead.

**Edit:**

Now that you've edited your question to be a little more specific...

The Arduino is a great prototyping and development kit. I skipped Basic Stamps and PIC when they started becoming popular, and wound up getting back into electronics when the Arduino first showed up. From the Arduino, I quickly realized that I wanted to be able to program small microcontrollers without the rest of the development board, and learned how to work with Atmel AVR microcontrollers, which are at the heart of the Arduino.

So, my recommendation is to work on the Arduino more, doing projects that are of interest. You might want to pick up a book like the [Arduino Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802486.do) or any of the thousands of online tutorials from sites like [MakerShed](http://www.makershed.com/Arduinos_Microcontrollers_s/43.htm) and [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Projects/).

Since you're in engineering, I'll assume you're getting the basic coursework for DC and AC electronics, semiconductors and digital electronics. That will provide a solid background for branching out from the Arduino and developing your own support circuitry, prototyping on breadboards, experimenting with other microcontrollers, and perhaps designing your own boards.