# Start in Eletronics/Hardware with Eletronic or Arduino Book?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I've already received several suggestions about what some people read to start my development in relation to hardware / electronics. I already have a good knowledge in languages ​​such as C, C + +, Python, and now I want to improve my knowledge.

I received recommendations to start learning with books like **Practical Electronics for Inventors** or **The Art of Electronics**, **Arduino** and some books, but do not know if I start earlier with the theory of electronics or if there is any book that covers these concepts along with Arduino.

Could you help me? I'm 17 and a lot of encouragement in learning

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment becaust I haven't read those books. If you specifically plan on starting with an arduino, there's no harm in checking out the adafruit tutorials: http://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-arduino  they're pretty basic and walk you through the hardware side a little bit.

I would, however, look into basic electronics as well. You don't need to know semiconductor theory but once you know about logic gates, op-amps and RLC circuit theory (basics), you'll be well on your way.

Comment: @ChrisL Thanks! Pretty cool!! I will look into this guide

Comment: On Stack Exchange sites questions regarding specific book / product recommendations are discouraged in general because they are largely based on opinion or quickly become obsolete. But the following Community Wiki [Basic Electronic Books](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book) may be of interest.

Comment: Arduino is not electronics, it's (not very good) software. I'd recommend "Getting Started In Electronics" by Forrest M Mims III as a basic 1st book. Electronic Systems by M. W. Brimicombe was our college book and has a good approach, treating things you don't yet need to know as a black box. Aside from that, practice / play / hack. Read dangerousprototypes and hackaday, but note that Hackaday feature some very ugly junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to improve your knowledge about electronics, arduino and everything else, **is practicing**.

As you are from Brazil like me, I recommend the site [Laboratorio de Garagem](http://labdegaragem.com/), they have a forum with tutorials and projects and a lot of kits, sensors and everything that you will need to start practicing.

Comment: +1 on "practicing". This seems to be something that is often overlooked these days for aspiring engineers. I got my start with ham radio shack/electronics lab in the basement. The web site you provided looks promising. [GarageLab](http://garagelab.com/) appears to be the English language version.

Comment: @Tut I agree with you, pratcicing was very important for me too. And, yes its is the same site. The site that I recommended its the brazilian subsidiary, its a very good site.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't read every Arduino book in existence, I can pretty confidently say there is no single book that covers both Arduino and all the theory and practice in AoE and PEI. Several of the popular Arduino books have *some* electronics theory and circuit advice in them, but every one I have read so far has spent most of its limited page count on the software and platform aspects of Arduino.

As a programmer first and an electronics guy second, I'd tell you to start with an Arduino book first, then dig into as much electronics as you need to get things done. To me, electronics is usually a means to an end, rather than something I want to study for its own sake.

Other people may tell you to go the other way, learning a bunch of theory before you jump into Arduino. These people are not wrong. You will avoid making a bunch of newbie mistakes if you do it this way, because you will have a better idea of why things are the way they are. This will help you ask better questions and find answers on your own.

Bottom line, get an Arduino book *and* either [PEI](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/reviews/pei.html) or [AoE](http://tangentsoft.net/elec/reviews/aoe2.html). The links take you to my reviews of those books so you can choose between them. (My PEI book review hasn't yet been updated for the third edition.)

Comment: I like your practical thinking