# Learning electronic circuit design

Tags: integrated-circuit, basic

Is there a good website or book to learn electronic circuit design from the beginning.
I would like to learn more about basic electronic elements and how to use transistors appropriately in my circuit designs and learn more about popular IC s and their applications.

Comment: In addition to answers posted below, also try searching this site using keyword "learning" for a bunch of other probably useful suggestions. Videos. Simulation software. Particular focused application areas that might appeal to you and add motivation.

Comment: thread on [Basic Electronics Books](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book)

Comment: Please search for a good book on electronics. look for ISBN-10: 0521370957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill: not very new but is well loved for its excellent practical approach to teaching fundamentals.

Comment: Horowitz and Hill

Answer (score 2):

Start developing small embedded projects.
Read good embedded system magazines, example, circuit cellar and elektor.

Comment: Check out free video lectures and tutorials from top universities at http://freevideolectures.com/