# Beginning Audio Electronics

Tags: audio, books

I'm 16 and interested in getting into audio electronics so I can make things like mixers and speakers, etc. I currently only have a rudimentary understanding of electrical circuits which extends only to that contained in the book Make: Electronics.

I'm seeking out advice and recommendations of any books or online courses for either electronics in general or audio electronics specifically.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks that helps but what about books specifically on audio?

Comment: Lots of books use examples in audio because the concept is easy to grasp. Books specifically on audio electronics usually require a good understanding of basic electronics. You'll need the basics before you can specialize in a particular subject.

Comment: Coursera has some nice online courses which might interest you. You can join them for free if you like.

Comment: Coursera's [Linear Circuits](https://www.coursera.org/course/circuits) is possibly accessible, only a little calculus but well worth a look even if you don't complete it.

Answer (score 1):

This question strongly suggests that you haven't looked very hard for available resources.  Here's a hint:  drop the following string into Google and start following the links shown:

audio circuits book (guitar, mixer)

Craig Anderton wrote a very good book many years ago that is still highly regarded titled "Electronic Projects for Musicians".  I see that it was recently (2010) updated.

Another good resource is [Elliott Sound Products](https://sound-au.com/) - head over to the Projects page.

Answer (score 0):

Well you might read about opamps.  I don't suppose you have any test gear? ('scope, power supplies?)  Get a DMM, soldering iron... A linear power supply is a good first project.  And you get a power supply that you can use for the next project.