# Electrical engineering beginners book

Tags: books

This maybe the wrong forum to be asking such a broad question but I'm looking for an EE book that was referenced by a friend years ago.

The whole book looks as though it were scanned copies of a notebook. It provided the fundamentals of electrical circuits along with what looked like hand written notes in it.

I know, extremely broad but he mentioned that a lot of EE individuals loved it.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book

Comment: Please read the guidelines of the fourm *before* posting http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Q&A site not forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I owned those years ago. I picked them up from Radio Shack back in the 80's. If I remember correctly, they were written by Forrest Mims. I did a quick search and all I could find that might be a newer version was [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=a_B4dCFFL2oC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Forrest%20Mims%20electronics%20booklets&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhgIzlw4PRAhVY4GMKHS-bBM8Q6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Hey! That's it!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I loved those things.