# A good way to get into Electronics with just 2 hours per week?

Tags: arduino, hobbyist

I want to get into electronics but I only have 2 hours per week to spend time-wise and my budget is low. What are some good projects? Perhaps I should spend my time doing C programming challenges instead... and then when I have more time and money get into the hardware?

Comment: With only two hours left you should better watch a TV show

Comment: Find a project that motivates you and you'll find the time.

Comment: As sstobbe suggests, start a project of interest to you.  Start with something simple.  The more complex it is, the least likely you will complete it or get any thing out of it.

Answer (score 5):

You wont learn much with two hours a week... Electronic is not that easy, you will just learn very basic things and forget it for the next week ! However, if you are ready to spend 30min - 40min a day in electronic, I recommend you to look at Arduino tutorial. Most of the time it cover basic C langage as well as very basic electronic. Bu doing so, you will understand the very basic electronic.

If you want to go further in the electronic, I recommend you to buy a electronic book. This post cover lots of book. You can make your choice ;)

[Basic Electronics Book](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/616/116604)

Another alternative is to join electronic workshop if there is one in your city